# MySQL: can't insert a record because a foreign key issue

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have this schema
[image]

when i'm trying to add a new `isp_share` record I get this error

[image]

although isp table has a record with `id=3`

[image]

what could be the problem?

Comment: In your insert why is isp_idisp omitted?

Comment: @Mihai it's the last argument in the insert statement

Comment: Are you sure that you working on the right database and not on a copy?

Comment: @chumkiu I'm sure... I have a single copy of the database that I'm working on... I'm even working on PHPMyAdmin to insert the record

Comment: Try it without quotes on the last 3.

Comment: @Mihai still the same error

Comment: Are those table both on the same engine?

Comment: @Mihai I was going to tell you the problem is that `isp_share` working on InnoDB and `isp` is working on MyISAM
Now both are working on InnoDB and problem solved
can you post a solution of your own... and if you have info about why that happened can you explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> The parent and child tables must use the same storage
>   engine..Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced
>   key must have similar data types

Also do a check of the other tables.